# Visa restrictions while travelling with step children

Tags: visas, tourist-visas

We are intending to travel from Auckland, via Sydney, through Johannesburg to Windhoek in late June. There we want to join a truck safari through Botswana and ending in Zimbabwe.

Stay there for a couple of days before flying to Egypt for two weeks, transiting in Addis Ababa.

From there back home to NZ transiting Dubai.

The family group consists of me, my wife and her two 14 year old girls - my step daughters.

We are aware that we cannot disembark in South Africa due to the restrictions around Step-parents traveling with children and the requirement for permission from the other natural parent - whom in this case is absent and we have no idea where.

What I am trying to establish is whether we will find similar restrictions to any other parts of this trip? Or indeed if there are any other visa requirements for our trip.

I've looked tat multiple websites for travel visas and it looks like we'll be ok with Egypt and Zimbabwe requiring entry visas, nothing for Namibia or Botswana for NZ citizens and the two transit stops are fine as we are booked forward to the next destination.

What we're really trying to establish is - have we missed something that might trip us up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What country issued your passports?

Comment: South Africa is fine if your wife has sole custody--take the court order/paperwork. That might work in other jurisdictions.

Comment: Passport country is New Zealand. Sole custody is only because the father has been absent for 6 years. So no documentation to support that

Comment: I suggest getting judicial notice of the father's abandonment of your step-daughters will be permanently useful. If your step-daughters' passports have their father's surname, you may get questioned by border guards in any country, not just South Africa, with unpredictable results.